# Unit testing in VS2010 - "Run" passes, "Debug" fails

Tags: .net, unit-testing, debugging

I have a testcase, when I Run the testcase in VS2010, the testcase passes.

But, later I found out that the testcase was not correct,  the assertion in CheckStatus() method should fail, and I got the assertion fail when I Debug the testcase.

So what can be the reason that testcase passes in Run mode?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod() {
        Invokable.Invoke(() => TestApplication.AnEvent+= CheckStatus);
        try {
            TestApplication.SearchCommand.Execute();
            Assert.AreEqual(State.Update, TestApplication.State);
        } finally {
            Invokable.Invoke(() => {
                TestApplication.AnEvent -= CheckStatus);
            });
        }
    }

    private void CheckStatus() {
        Assert.AreEqual(State.Initial, TestApplication.State);
    }
```

Comment: It is cross-thread testing.  It seems that the testcase treats the failed assertion from CheckStatus() as an exception, as I can see the TestApplication.SearchCommand.Execute() is interrupted inside. But I still do not understand why the testcase passes in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a timing issue, perhaps caused by code in Debug mode running slower.

The calls to `Invoke` give a clue that you're doing cross-thread communication. If so, look in to how to synchronise between threads before further testing, as it is possible that the test is running before the invoke has had a chance to be invoked.

You could test this yourself with a `Thread.Sleep()` before the `Execute()` method.

Comment: Are you sure the `CheckStatus` test is running at all? Perhaps set a flag to `true` after the `Assert` in the `CheckStatus` method. Test for it being `true` before the `Execute()` method (in Run/Debug modes).

Comment: Ýes, the CheckStatus() is running. If I put a try..catch..in CheckStatus(), an exception is caught.